# AWS DMS Removing LOB Columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-migration, data-migration, aws-dms, dms

I'm trying to set up a Postgresql migration using the DMS to s3 as target. But after running I noticided that some tables were missing some columns.
After checking the logs I noticed this message:

```
Column 'column_name' was removed from table definition 'schema.table': the column data type is LOB and the table has no primary key or unique index
```

In the settings of the task migration I tried to increase the lob limit in the option
Maximum LOB size to 2000000

But still getting the same result.
Does anyone know a workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, the problem is you do not have the primary key in your table.
From AWS documentation:

> Currently, a table must have a primary key for AWS DMS to capture LOB
> changes. If a table that contains LOBs doesn't have a primary key,
> there are several actions you can take to capture LOB changes:
>
> - Add a primary key to the table. This can be as simple as adding an ID
>   column and populating it with a sequence using a trigger.
> - Create a materialized view of the table that includes a
>   system-generated ID as the primary key and migrate the materialized
>   view rather than the table.
> - Create a logical standby, add a primary key to the table, and migrate
>   from the logical standby.
>   [Learn more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.Oracle.LOBChanges)

It is also important to have the primary key of a simple type, not LOB:

> In FULL LOB or LIMITED LOB mode, AWS DMS doesn't support replication of primary keys that are LOB data types.
> [Learn more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.General.PKLOBColumn)